# Ajax execute php without refresh - how to set variables?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a very small php script which in which I have a few buttons and no form. When I press one button, I want a small php script to be executed based on the id that I'm trying to send using ajax.

Those buttons look like this:

```
<button onclick="deleteTask()" class="task" data-id="1">Task 1</button>
<button onclick="deleteTask()" class="task" data-id="2">Task 3</button>
<button onclick="deleteTask()" class="task" data-id="3">Task 4</button>
...
```

And I have this ajax function:

```
function deleteTask() {
    var id=$(this).data("id");
    var dataString='id='+ id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success:function(html) {
            alert(html);
        }
    });
}
```

The PHP script that is executed is just a test:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo "Response: " . $id;
```

And the result is that alert box with a response of:

```
Response: undefined
```

What I want is to get that data-id of the button that was pressed as a response. If I press button `1` with `data-id="1"` I want to get a response of `"1"`.

Comment: try `data: { 'id': id }`

Comment: hey Dan! Thanks for this but it gives a notificitaion of undefined index now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, `$(this)` is the window object.

You may be thinking of using `$(this)` off the back of a jQuery event handler. When you do something like `$('#myElement').click(function() {...});`, `$(this)` will represent the element that has been clicked.

Is there a reason you cannot do something like this?

```
<button onclick="deleteTask(1)">Task 1</button>
<button onclick="deleteTask(3)">Task 3</button>

<script>
function deleteTask(id) {
    var dataString='id='+ id;

    ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: the reason for not doing this was my limited knowledge :D thank you so much!!!!! it woeked <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 2):

As @Andrew correctly said, `$(this)` is the *window* object.

So, in order to be able to reference the *button* object inside the function, you must pass it as function argument, e.g. as `this` in each function call:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteTask(button) {
        var id = $(button).data("id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: {
                'id': id
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<button type="button" id="button1" name="button1" onclick="deleteTask(this);" class="task" data-id="1">Task 1</button>
<button type="button" id="button2" name="button2" onclick="deleteTask(this);" class="task" data-id="2">Task 3</button>
<button type="button" id="button3" name="button3" onclick="deleteTask(this);" class="task" data-id="3">Task 4</button>
```